# Add share (contact) button for whatsapp and other messangers in website

Tags: javascript, android, html

How can I add a share button on the page of my site, we can add send SMS on mobile HTML pages with this code :

```
<a href="sms:?body=...">title</a>
```

And how can use this sample in share, such as Viber, Watsapp and etc

Comment: whatsapp has its own api. they use something like this `href="whatsapp://send" data-text="visit our website:"`. Better to research the api of the platforms you want to share to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html pages only. I normally use [AddThis](https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing) for all my sharing as it comes with stats and its free.

whatsapp has its own api. they use something like this

`href="whatsapp://send" data-text="visit our website:"`.

Better to research the api of the platforms you want to share to 
Whatsapp all has some script to embed in your page which generates the button but you can add a custom button also.

More info: [Sharing with whatsapp](http://whatsapp-sharing.com/)

Comment: user want something for Viber and watsapp, as much i know AddThis dont have any of it

Comment: @MazeRunner i use this api , but when clicking in this link, whatsapp open and closed then notify me sending field !

Comment: i updated my answer @user3415984 i forgot to include the reference link

Answer (score 0):

the answer i find it for whatsapp is :

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=... >Whatsapp</a>
```